# ALTER DATABASE db_name SET ENABLE_BROKER with rollback immediate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know what the impact would be by using the  `with rollback immediate`

Basically, in case in production the `ALTER DATABASE db_name SET ENABLE_BROKER` hangs and not working due to connection issue.

And I know that, `ALTER DATABASE db_name SET ENABLE_BROKER with rollback immediate` will always work.

But what is the possible impact for this statement really ?  Is it going to affect production ?
Assume production db is constantly busy doing stuff.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `with rollback immediate` clause of `alter database` essentially kills any active process in the database. So to answer your question of whether or not it will affect production, the answer is "very yes".